# How to ignore an html element in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, markdown

How to prevent Vue.js from running code within the < code > tags produced by markdown? It's a Laravel 5.5 + Vue.js 2.x project with 'andreasindal/laravel-markdown' package for markdown. The code that's Vue is trying to run is actually a Laravel Blade directive and it seems that Blade itself doesn't try to process it (since I'm getting a Vue error regarding this in the console).

```
{{ session('notificationType') }}
```

I tired modifying the Parsedown.php class (which is used by 'andreasindal/laravel-markdown') to replace all the '{' with the HTML ASCII characters. The replacement did work, but Vue still processed those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not want Vuejs to evaluate anything inside an HTML element you can use the `v-pre` directive as:

```
<code v-pre> {{ name }} </code>
```

In the above example vue will ignore everything inside the tags so, the `name` variable won't be evaluated and everything will be rendered as is.

<sup>[* more on v-pre](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I don't have a conflict with blade. I need to prevent Vue from processing {{ }} within < code > blocks only.

Comment: You can use `v-pre` as in `<code v-pre></code>` and all the `{{}}` will be displayed as is

Comment: Yep, this is it, thanks @samayo! You can edit your reply and I'll accept it.